# Python string should end up in dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, dictionary, error-handling

I'm trying to have this string end up in a dictionary but I receive error msg below. Any idea how to solve this? Thanks.

my code:

```
import ast
str = '{"success":true,"timestamp":1617349986,"base":"EUR","date":"2021-04-02","rates":{"USD":1.177996}}'
d = ast.literal_eval(str)
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xh\Documents\Other und Programme\Programme\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.3.1\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_exec2.py", line 3, in Exec
    exec(exp, global_vars, local_vars)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\xh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ast.py", line 91, in literal_eval
    return _convert(node_or_string)
  File "C:\Users\xh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ast.py", line 79, in _convert
    map(_convert, node.values)))
  File "C:\Users\xh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ast.py", line 90, in _convert
    return _convert_signed_num(node)
  File "C:\Users\xh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ast.py", line 63, in _convert_signed_num
    return _convert_num(node)
  File "C:\Users\xh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ast.py", line 55, in _convert_num
    raise ValueError('malformed node or string: ' + repr(node))
ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x00000215DF9CA248>
```

Comment: Your string is not valid Python. It looks like JSON. Why do you assume it is a Python literal?

Answer (score 0):

What you have is valid JSON. Don't use `ast.literal_eval`, use `json` module

```
import json
true
spam = '{"success":true,"timestamp":1617349986,"base":"EUR","date":"2021-04-02","rates":{"USD":1.177996}}'
eggs = json.loads(spam)
print(eggs)
```

As a side note - don't use `str` as name - it's a built-in function.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your string seems to be formatted in JSON format.

Using the `json` module:

```
import json

input_str = '{"success":true,"timestamp":1617349986,"base":"EUR","date":"2021-04-02","rates":{"USD":1.177996}}'

input_dict = json.loads(input_str)
print(input_dict)
```

Which gives:

`{'success': True, 'timestamp': 1617349986, 'base': 'EUR', 'date': '2021-04-02', 'rates': {'USD': 1.177996}}`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Solved my issue.